# Declaring XSLT variable pending value

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<ShoppingCart>

  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <LineItem>
    <extendedAttributes>
      <item>
        <name>RenewingSubscriptionID</name>
        <value>2106596709</value>
        <valueDataType>string</valueDataType>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>subscriptionLineItemId</name>
        <value>3145223500</value>
        <valueDataType>string</valueDataType>
      </item>
    </extendedAttributes>
  </LineItem>

  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <LineItem>
    <extendedAttributes>
      <item>
        <name>RenewingSubscriptionID</name>
        <value>2106596709</value>
        <valueDataType>string</valueDataType>
      </item>
    </extendedAttributes>
  </LineItem>

</ShoppingCart>
```

How do I go about in declaring an XSLTvariable that has value of `true` when the existence of `LineItem/extendedAttributes/item/name` has a value of `subscriptionLineItemId`? For the XML provided above, the desired behavior would be that `Item 1` would have the variable = `true`, while `Item 2` would have the variable = `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write something like this

```
<xsl:template match="LineItem">
  <xsl:variable name="has-item-id" select="boolean(extendedAttributes/item[name = 'subscriptionLineItemId'])"/>
  <has-item-id><xsl:value-of select="$has-item-id"/></has-item-id>
</xsl:template>
```

From the perspective of the `LineItem` element, the XPath expression finds all `extendedAttributes/item` elements that have the desired value of `name`, and converts the resulting node set to a boolean value. An empty node set converts to `false`.